# how can I send the form data from a native jquery mobile app to a remote server?

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, xcode4.2

I am using the following technologies:
- jQuery Mobile 1.0.1
- Phonegap 1.3.0
- Xcode 4.2

When I try to submit form data to a remote server, I get success using the application through the browser.

When I try to submit form data to a remote server using the application natively, I can not send.

I need some plugin PhoneGap?
I need some setup Xcode?

The following sample code was run on the iPhone Simulator 5.0:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
                            $('#output').html('Connecting....');
                            var postTo = 'http://myserver/login.php';

                            $.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() , password: $('[name=password]').val()} , 
                                function(data) {

                                if(data.message) {
                                    $('#output').html(data.message);
                                } else {
                                    $('#output').html('Could not connect');
                                }

                                },'json');

                return false;
                });
        });
        </script>

    </head> 

    <body> 

        <!-- Start of first page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="foo">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   

                <p id="output"></p>

                <form method="post" id="loginForm">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br /> <br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Login">

                </form>


            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /header -->
        </div><!-- /page -->


    </body>

</html>
```

In my server: (login.php)

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {

            if ($_POST['username'] == 'test' and $_POST['password'] == 'test') {

            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Login succesful';

            } else {

            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['message'] = 'Login failed';

            }

        // return json
        echo json_encode($data);

        }
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? Does the AJAX callback run? If not, add an `error` callback to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile examples use AJAX request not `$.post`.

This blog entery uses `$.ajax` and jQuery Mobile
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1948

This this other one uses a XMLHttpRequest:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample

Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: `$.post` is the same thing as `$.ajax({ type : 'post' })`

Comment: True, but I would be tempted to change it to match the giantflyingsauscer example just to be 100% sure.

Comment: thank you for the indication of the article.
I tested the code and got a 401 error response
I will continue trying to solve

thanks for the help

Answer (score -4):

I don't know if it's helpful but your PHP uses "and" on line 4 but I think it should use && to test if the posted variables are both called test.

Comment: Sorry, wrong.  **and** and **&&** are both logical operators with the same basic meaning, just different precedence.